# SQL server 2008 Cast varchar to money in a function is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a function that fails when cast a varchar value to money value, I added to the script an isnull check to verify that the problem was not the null casting.

Despite this and other attemps of discovering whether an specified value is the problem I have not been able to solve that.

The function script is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_casting
(@t  VARCHAR(2),
 @q  VARCHAR(17),
 @Q1 VARCHAR(17),
 @Q2 VARCHAR(17),
 @Q3 VARCHAR(17)
)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @Qf MONEY;
         SET @Qf = -1;
         IF @t = '2'
             BEGIN
                 DECLARE @MAX MONEY;
                 SET @MAX = 0;
                 IF ISNUMERIC(@Qmed) = 1
                     SET @Qmed = CAST(isnull(STUFF(@Qmed, 10, 0, '.'), 0) AS MONEY);
                 SET @Qf = @Qmed;
         END;
         RETURN ROUND(@Qf, 2);
     END;
```

Does anybody knows if there is some problem with cast in functions, or with money data type?
If I change the @QF data type to varchar it works.

Comment: wht ur trying to achieve ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma casting a varchar value to money

Comment: We're not mind readers. What do you mean by "fails"? What data are you putting into this function? Without that info we're just guessing

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody wants to ask - "can this string be converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care which ones)?" You don't want to attempt the conversion here if, say, the string can only be converted to a `float`.

Comment: Also, the current code in the question isn't your actual code since it fails to declare `@QMed` as either a parameter or a variable. Trying to guess what's wrong with code when we're not even shown the real code makes things even more problematic. Please try to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Why you are going  in `function` for small casting, this could be also done by using small `sql` script

```
declare @value varchar(max)

set @value = '10'

select CAST(@value as money)
```

Result :

```
10.00
```

Comment: Hi,
Can you please try to convert @ to money format? like this:
    SET @Qf = CONVERT(MONEY, COALESCE(@Qmed, 0));
Hope this can help!

Comment: @Mohamad `declare @Qf money, @Qmed varchar(max)

SET @Qf = CONVERT(MONEY, COALESCE(@Qmed, 0));

select @Qf `